# Merging/Multiplying word lists on linux?

Tags: linux, password-generation

I don't believe there is a word for what I am describing, but heres what im trying to do:
I have two lists of words, one contains one word per line of adjectives, the other contains one line per word of nouns.

```bsh
## meaning the noun file looks like this
rabbit
airplane
curtain
   ### and the adjective file looks like this
purple
clean
thirsty
friendly
```

Now ill get to the point, the basic output of what i need is for one line to be selected (thirsty), and i want that one adjective to be paired with every line of another text file. The output is expected to look as such:

```bsh
thirstyrabbit
thirstycurtain
thirstyairplane
```

and when it's done with that line, it needs to move to the next one and start over:

```bsh
cleanrabbit
cleancurtain
cleanairplane
```

anyone know how to do this with linux commands? Sorry for the terrible descripption but i dont know how to describe what i want without demonstration.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1620946/10765659). I found it by creating a term "cartesian product of two text files" and googling. Also check [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11343/108618).

Comment: Why is the sequence `rabbit`, `airplane`, `curtain` in the input but `rabbit`, `curtain`, `airplane` in the output? In addition you start with `thirsty` and call `clean` "the next one", while it's `purple`, `clean`, `thirsty`, `friendly` in the input. What are the strict rules for the output sequence then? Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did exactly what I wanted:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r a; do while IFS= read -r b; do echo "$a$b"; done < (SecondFile); done < (FirstFile) > output.txt
```